# django: a model can be accessed from shell, but fail from web ui

Tags: django

I have models like

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='customer_profile' , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='mycustomer' , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False)
    id_card = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    provinsi = models.ForeignKey(Provinsi, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    kota = models.ForeignKey(Kota, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    kecamatan = models.ForeignKey(Kecamatan, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    desa = models.ForeignKey(Desa, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    kodepos = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gmap = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class ContractCode(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=8)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.code

class BaseContract(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    code = models.OneToOneField(ContractCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # -- location
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    provinsi = models.ForeignKey(Provinsi, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    kota = models.ForeignKey(Kota, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    kecamatan = models.ForeignKey(Kecamatan, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    desa = models.ForeignKey(Desa, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    kodepos = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gmap = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=100)

    # EOL location

    step = models.IntegerField(choices=ContractStep.choices,
        default=ContractStep.SURVEY_WAIT.value,
        editable=False)
    open_close = models.IntegerField(choices=JobStatus.choices,
        default=JobStatus.OPEN.value,
        verbose_name='status',
        editable=False)
    is_enable = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    odp = models.ForeignKey(ODP, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ont = models.OneToOneField(ONT, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True)

    ppp_pw = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True,
        verbose_name='PPP Password')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.code)
    
    def ppp_un(self) -> str:
        str_id = str(self.id)
        retval = ''.join(str_id.split('-'))
        return retval
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding :
            if not self.address1:
                self.address1 = self.customer.address1
            if not self.address2:
                self.address2 = self.customer.address2
            if not self.address3:
                self.address3 = self.customer.address3
            if not self.provinsi:
                self.provinsi = self.customer.provinsi
            if not self.kota:
                self.kota = self.customer.kota
            if not self.kecamatan:
                self.kecamatan = self.customer.kecamatan
            if not self.desa:
                self.desa = self.customer.desa
            if not self.kodepos:
                self.kodepos = self.customer.kodepos
            if not self.gmap:
                self.gmap = self.customer.gmap

            while True:
                try:
                    new_code = ContractCode()
                    new_code.code = random_string(8)
                    new_code.save()
                    self.code = new_code
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
            self.status = ContractStep.SURVEY_WAIT.value
        return super(BaseContract, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Contract'
```

admin.py looks like

```
from django.contrib import admin
from setup.models import Company
from setup.utils import get_user_company
from business.models import Customer, BaseContract
from .forms import MarketingCustomerForm
import uuid
# Register your models here.

class MarketingContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #list_filter = ('customer',)
    form = MarketingCustomerForm
    exclude = ['code', 'odp', 'ont','ppp_pw']
    change_form_template = 'lokasi_change.html'

    def get_form(self, request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        form = super(MarketingContractAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request) :
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(company = get_user_company(request.user))


    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "company":
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                kwargs['queryset'] = Company.objects.filter(id = get_user_company(request.user).id)
                kwargs['initial'] = kwargs['queryset'].first()

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(BaseContract, MarketingContractAdmin)

class MarketingCustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MarketingCustomerForm
    change_form_template = 'lokasi_change.html'

    def get_form(self, request,obj=None,**kwargs):
        form = super(MarketingCustomerAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request) :
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(company = get_user_company(request.user))
        
        return qs

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "company":
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
                kwargs['queryset'] = Company.objects.filter(id = get_user_company(request.user).id)
                kwargs['initial'] = kwargs['queryset'].first()

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Customer, MarketingCustomerAdmin)
```

Creating a customer via web ui have no problem.

But when I click 'Business>Contracts' menu (as SuperUser ), I got :

```
Something’s wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user.
```

I test it using django shell

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from business.models import Customer, BaseContract
>>> c = Customer.objects.first()
>>> bc = BaseContract.objects.create(customer=c)
>>> xx = BaseContract.objects.first()
>>> xx.customer
<Customer: customer01>
>>> xx.customer.name
'customer01'
>>>
```

So i'm prety sure that the database and that 2 tables is ok .

Kindly please tell me how to fix it or how to trace the problem

Sincerely
-bino-